# FME ArcSDE.... the scale is very small

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, fme-form

I have a problem with ArcSde and FME. I try to import some line features to ArcSDE Oracle. When I start the script in FME, I have some errors: impossible to insert linestring in ArcSde because the scale is very small. The length of linestring is equal at 100 meters.

But I have the others geometry with the same length and there is no problem to insert theses features in ArcSDE.
So, i have no idea on this problem. 
Is it possible to clean geometry with FME ? or a correction of geometry ?
(I try Geometry Filter, OGC validator, but nothing).
Thanks

Error:
***Line Feature not allowed in table 'CHEMN'. Migration attempted
Error while generating simple line shape for Table 'CHEMIN'. Scale Factor may be too small.:SDE_ERROR_CODE(-155) Linestring or poly boundary is self-intersecting
Error while setting the shape to 'sde30_nil' for feature in table 'CHEMIN'. Shape Type Not Allowed - Change Table Def.:SDE_ERROR_CODE(-35) Shapes of this entity type not allowed in this layer***

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution:

1. I use ArcSDEGridSnapper with the parameters (xmin,ymin, scale... See the spatial reference in ArcSde Oracle).
2. GeometryFilter
3. GeometryValidator
4. SelfIntersector for split the linestring.
5. Import data to ArcSde.

Bingo !!